# Installing Gulp gives me these warnings

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

My Node version : `v0.12.2` 
My npm version: `2.7.4`

I ran the following command: `npm install gulp -g`

Should I care ? I get these warnings:

```
C:\Users\Maddy\Desktop\PublicServer\skill_tests>npm install gulp -g
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
```

Comment: I got those as well and my gulp tasks run fine. I would go ahead and write some tasks and try them to see if gulp is working. If not, get back to us on here!

Comment: I only noticed it throwing these within the last few months, but it's really annoying when every other dependency has it together and doesn't have warnings to pollute logs.

Answer (score 2):

Those error warnings are not a major issue. I get the same warnings when I install gulp. I have been using it for a while. It has to do with the libraries that support gulp. Gulp has dependencies and those dependencies are "packaged" together to create gulp. For example lodash is a javascript library that has a lot of array utilities. But lodash is maintained by the person who developed it

If you look in the node_modules folder you can see all the dependencies that make up gulp. I just pointed out lodash because you can find the link [here](https://lodash.com/) and review it yourself. Gulp is not one javascript library it's a compilation of several projects that make up one tool.

Answer (score 1):

Since `npm` has no kind of a rating system -- or anything remotely similar, there are a lot of "old" packages out there that refer to other "old" packages.

And, for the most part, that is fine.

For the most part being the key phrase.

Once in a rare while there may be a breaking change to node which causes one of these old packages to fail and you can get a cascading error upwards.  However, it doesn't seem to happen too often -- I've only run into it once.

The bottom line is: Unless you are able to maintain the packages, there isn't really anything you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

All of these are warnings, which means you should be fine. If you encounter an error run:

```
npm list
```

which will give you a list of dependencies and packages. Generally speaking, these have to be updated by the author. So you if it's mission critical give them a ping on their repos or find alternatives that are maintained.